# My RedirectTo Fails

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a redirectTo a cloud page that is breaking when the GA setup at the account level is appended when I do a test send.

My link is the following:

```
<a alias="Inspire" conversion="false" data-linkto="other" href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1492,'SubscriberKey',_subscriberkey,'&email',emailaddr,'&MID',memberid,'&JobID',jobid))=%%" style="color:#302A3d;text-decoration:underline;" title="">Redirect to cloud page</a>
```

I managed to bypass this by using the IIF function in the following script:

```
%%[SET @urlDefault='https://www.contiki.com'
SET @nolink=''
SET @Inspire=CloudPagesURL(1492,'SubscriberKey',_subscriberkey,'&email',emailaddr,'&MID',memberid,'&JobID',jobid)
]%%


<a href="%%=RedirectTo(IIF(@nolink,v(@urlDefault),v(@Inspire)))=%%" title="inspire" alias="inspire" conversion="undefined">Redirect to Inspire tab</a>
```

Is there a better way to rewrite this so the marketers don't need to use the amp script piece of code?

Giulietta

Comment: Hi, are you sure you need to add the "&" signs in the CloudPagesURL function?
I think it should look like this:


CloudPagesURL(1492,'SubscriberKey',_subscriberkey,'email',emailaddr,'MID',memberid,'JobID',jobid)



Also I believe that you can just use _subscriberKey personalization string on the cloudpage without sending it through CloudPagesUrl() function in a custom parameter.

Comment: @Jonas Lamberty include it as answer. And yes on a cloudpage you can use _subscriberkey without transmitting it, seems like Lukas was faster :D

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on **[Jonas'](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/59501/jonas-lamberty)**, answer: You don't need to pass all these values, as they are implicitly provided by the CloudPagesURL function. Hence you just should link by using:

```
<a alias="Inspire" conversion="false" data-linkto="other" href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(1492))=%%" style="color:#302A3d;text-decoration:underline;" title="">Redirect to cloud page</a>
```

In the Cloud Page, you can reference these Personalisation Strings, as stated [here](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/):

> This encrypted query string provides a reference to the email, which
>   means that system personalization strings can be used on a landing
>   page to retrieve values related to the sent email. And as the string
>   is encrypted, no Subscriber information is passed in clear text.

This should make this approach less prone to break.